# How to read data from a generic list List<T> in java

Tags: java, android, collections, arraylist

I have a generic list as shown below.

```
protected List<T> mItems;

 public ArrayAdapter(final List<T> objects, final boolean copyList) {
        if (objects != null) {
            if (copyList) {
                mItems = new ArrayList<T>(objects);
            } else {
                mItems = objects;
            }
        } else {
            mItems = new ArrayList<T>();
        }
 }
```

I want get an integer value at a specific location from `mItems`. Where `mItems` contains a objects of a model class.

**--EDIT--**

I don't have access to model class, that's why it is `List<T>` otherwise I could use `List<MyModelClass>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood it correctly, but what about:

```
public packagename.MyClass getItemAtPosition(int position)
{
  Object item = mItems.get(position);
  if(item instanceof packagename.MyClass)
  {
    return (packagename.MyClass)item;
  }
  return null;
}
```

With this, you'll have access to all the methods of MyClass and you can extract the Integer from it.

Since you don't have access (for what ever reasons) to MyClass, you could use reflexion to get the integer from item. A quick search should get you started with reflexion.

Comment: The "item" is not returning an Integer instead it is returning an object of class (MyClass) which has 1 integer and 1 string

Comment: @pokerface So cast to that object and extract the integer you want? Also, it sounds like you need bounds on your generic parameter, or you need to specify the type of the `List` explicitly. That way you don't have to do any casting at all.

Comment: problem is I cannot cast it, this code is part of a library where that MyClass is not accessible.

Comment: @pokerface What do you mean by "not accessible"? As in its visibility modifier doesn't let you see it?

Comment: The code i have written in question is a part of android library which is using generic list to handle all lists with all types (even custom). I am passing my List<MyClass> to this library which converts its to List<?>

Comment: @pokerface: what does System.out.println(mList.get(0).getClass()); output?

Comment: it gives packagename.MyClass

Comment: @pokerface: either place at the beginning an import packagename.MyClass and use MyClass in your code or use the code I provided in the answer. If it does not work, please provide more details. I'll be back after my meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generic list you should use Interface, which has declared method (extract data).

Comment: Generic list is part of a library, and by changing it there will be ripple effects, so I cannot change that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
protected List<T extends YourClass> mItems;
```

After that you will see methods of YourClass

This is sample of code how you can use generic class:

```
public class GenericClass <T extends GenericClass.MyClass>{
    T object;

public GenericClass(T object) {
    this.object = object;
}

public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println(object.helloWorld());
}

public static class MyClass{
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello world";  
    }
}
}
```